# SSH connection issue Cloudera Manager on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, cloudera-manager

I have installed Cloudera Manager on a Google Compute Engine VM and successfully logged in to CM. I am trying to create a 3 node Hadoop (YARN) cluster there. However, on the ssh credentials page, where I am providing my username without password, the process is failing (`error: Exhausted available authentication methods`).

I tried creating password less ssh login manually. Created the `id_rsa` and copied `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_host`. I was able to ssh to the same machine but not to other machine (I did copy the instance-1 `id_rsa.pub` to the instance-2's `authorized_keys`).

Comment: What OS distribution are you using on GCE?

Comment: I am using Debian based Linux 7.8 (wheezy)

Comment: By `authorized_host`, did you mean `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: Yes @MishaBrukman , i meant ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. BTW that problem is solved now. I had to change PasswordAuthentication no to yes in the sshd_config file. Cluster is running fine now.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please move your solution into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that PasswordAuthentication was set to no in the ssh config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config). So while doing ssh it was not checking for password authentication hence did not ask for password. Changing this to yes solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I have made a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/cloudera/manager) which has scripts to build images with Cloudera Manager preinstalled which you might want to consider using.

By default, GCE OS images only support public-key SSH authentication, not password, so if you want to use password, you have to modify [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH) to allow this; see [this script](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/blob/master/apps/cloudera/cdh5/manager/scripts/common/cloudera-user.sh) for details on how.

As an alternative, you can also deploy [Cloudera Director on GCE](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/cloudera/director) which will properly configure your instances and install Cloudera Manager for you.

Comment: Thanks for the script, but i want to know what is going wrong here?

Comment: update: I have created a separate cloudera user(hadoop) according to your script. Now i can do ssh to other nodes using hadoop user without any password but cloudera manager still not able to do ssh and got this error in the CM log. <br/> net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods. <br/> Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: keyboard-interactive auth not allowed by server

Comment: If you can ssh yourself but Cloudera Manager cannot given the same credentials, that sounds like a CM issue. Maybe ask this on one of Cloudera's community forums? See http://community.cloudera.com/