# cloudera cluster installation failed on docker

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, cloudera-manager

I am very new to cloudera. I'm trying to add a host in cloudera manager but it fails with following error

> Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.
>
> 1. Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
> 2. Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager Server (check firewall rules).
> 3. Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are not in use on the host being added.
> 4. Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added. (Some of the logs can be found in the installation
>    details).
> 5. If Use TLS Encryption for Agents is enabled in Cloudera Manager (Administration -> Settings -> Security), ensure that
>    /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini has use_tls=1 on the host being
>    added. Restart the corresponding agent and click the Retry link here.

I'm running cloudera-quickstart-vm (https://github.com/caioquirino/docker-cloudera-quickstart) in a docker container running on ubuntu based google cloud VM.
I create a tunnel to cloudera manager using PuTTY on port 172.17.xx.1:7180 where the IP is the docker IP. I access it in browser as localhost:7180
This same IP resolves as hostname in first step of adding new host.

When I run "hostname" command in my container, I get the container id e.g. 0cb223fcfe64. If I try to add this as a hostname I get message "Could not connect to host"

How can I resolve these errors and add a new host?

I have reviewed other similar posts on stackoverflow and cloudera forum but none of the solutions worked for me. If any more information is required, let me know and I will try to provide more details.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30993065/3618671) to another question for an alternative way to run Cloudera Manager and Cloudera Director which you may find useful. For issues with this specific Docker image, please consider filing an issue in the author's GitHub project as it may be specific to their configuration.

Comment: I'm currently on the free trial of GCE so cannot build a customized VM required for Cloudera director. I turned on the password authentication in sshd_config and am now locked out of my VM. I will try the script next

Comment: You can also run Cloudera Director locally on your own computer and use it  to control a Cloudera Cluster on Google Cloud Platform: just [install it manually from packages](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/cloudera/director/quickstart#manual-installation), provide it with a JSON file with your Google Cloud project credentials, and let it deploy and build clusters.

Comment: In manual installation section, I'm unable to access the instructions for other operating systems. Page says "No resource found". could you share the link again? And thank you so much for all your help @MishaBrukman

Comment: I think the problem here is that the private key file I give to cloudera allows it to access the GCE VM but not docker.

Comment: instructions to install cloudera-director on ubuntu: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Director-Cloud-based/How-do-I-install-cloudera-director-The-sudo-command-says-unable/m-p/22335#M89

Comment: Looks like Cloudera moved their documentation; here are the [latest docs for installing Director](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/director/latest.html). I've updated my GitHub repo to point to this URL; thanks for letting me know about the change!